# Find EXACT app in App Store

Tags: ios-appstore

I just got an AT&T SIM and was looking for an app to manage the account.

A search came up with **myAT&T** but when I try to search the App Store on the phone I get dozens of irrelevant apps, but **NOT** what I was looking for.

How can I find EXACT app in App Store

EDIT

I searched in Safari (on the phone with the AT&T SIM), and clicked the link in the answer, but the result says "This app is only available on the App Store for iOS devices"

I am in the US - connected to AT&T, running iOS 10.3.3 (the latest for the iPhone5C)

---

I can launch the App Store app, but there is no download link, and it states "This app is only available on the App Store for iOS devices".

On my iPad I get an error "The item you've requested is not currently available in the Australian Store" - so I guess my problem then becomes how to use the US Store.

Comment: Were you able to launch the App Store app?

Comment: It appears that the required app is not available in the App Store of your country. You can follow the instructions in this article to change the App Store country: https://www.imore.com/how-change-countries-itunes-and-app-store-iphone-or-ipad

Answer (score 1):

Here is the app you are looking for:

[myAT&T](https://itunes.apple.com/app/myat-t/id309172177)

The trick is to look for name of the app publisher shown under the app name.

[image]

Number and value of ratings is another factor to look for to ascertain the authenticity of the app coming from the intended publisher.

[image]

It is also a good idea to visit the service providers website and follow the App Store link for the app to ensure you are downloading the intended app.

Comment: I CAN find on my Mac using a browser, but not in the App Store, even though I searched for "myAT&T"

Comment: One possible explanation is that the app may not be available for your country in the App Store. Try opening the App Store link in the answer on your iPhone.