# Cannot change App Store Country

Tags: ios-appstore

I am in the US and want to download an app, only in the US Store.

I tried changing the App Store Country, but seem to hit an impasse.

When entering my Credit Card details I cannot select Australia as the billing address.

I have 2 MasterCards, one Travel Money card with $US, and my Australian card.

---

**I give up** - this is apparently not possible!

I can't change App Store Country without changing Family Sharing.

Comment: Are the cards you're trying to use issued with an Australian billing address?  Cards must be issued in the country of the App Store, not just usable in that country.

Comment: If you just want to download the myAT&T (free) app (as mentioned in the [other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/331823/find-exact-app-in-app-store) question), theres a workaround. You can create an alternate Apple ID, with USA as the country, without specifying any payment information. Once the ID is ready, log out from iTunes & App Store from Setting app and login with the new Apple ID. The App Store will be automatically switched to USA. Now, install the free app, logout from iTunes & App Store again and log back in with your original Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

A valid US postal address (could be your current hotel) is needed, and then you need to select NONE at the credit card - because you just buy some US iTunes gift cards, and load them into your new US Apple ID account, from where you'll pay for the apps you download.

And you can still use this US Apple ID when you are back in Australia - for app updates and new purchase from the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an IP located in the US to use the US AppStore.

You could try to use a VPN to simulate that you're in the USA.

Comment: I am afraid that's not correct. Using a VPN doesn't automatically switch the App Store country.